# Calculating speed at various points along a route for each device

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I want to calculate speed at every point for each device_id, such that there is a new column of "speed" is attached to the current dataset

My dataset is like

```
imei(device_id)         point_geom(SRID 4326)           time_created
```

Here is my code so far:

```
select st_distance((points_geom::geography),lag(points_geom::geography) over (partition by imei order by time_created))
 / (time_created - lag(time_created) over(partition by imei order by time_created))  as speed
from dataset
```

I am receiving this error:

```
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: double precision / interval
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arithmetic on two `TIMESTAMP` types return an `INTERVAL` type - use their `EPOCH` second representations instead:

```
( EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM time_created) - EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM LAG(time_created) OVER(PARTITION BY imei ORDER BY time_created))) )::FLOAT8
```

---

**Note:**

You *can* `EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM <INTERVAL>)` directly, however the internal `INTERVAL` transformation function *may* introduce integer rounding inaccuracies.

Comment: thanks, I fixed that. Is my logic / way of calculating speed okay? or should I first make separate columns for lagged time, and lagged point_geom, then do the final calculation on these columns?

Comment: also regarding the code you posted, does it give time difference in seconds? thanks

Comment: Looks good to me, as a simplified speed approximation. As long as execution speed is good enough, don't clutter you base tables with pure utility columns. And yes, the difference will be (decimal) seconds.